# how to set selected value in drop down menu depending on conditions

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have code with drop down menu. The object for this menu has few fields. Two of them are playerPosition and isFirstSquadPlayer.

If isFirstSquadPlayer is TRUE I need to display in menu player.playerPosition.
Trying on few ways but failed.
My controller:

```
    public String players(@PathVariable long clubId, Model model) {
        Club club = this.clubRepository.findByClubId(clubId);
        model.addAttribute("players", this.playerRepository.findAllByPlayerClub(club));
        return "players";
    }
```

My HTML:

```
<select name="playerposition"
     id="createnewplayerposition" th:value="${player.playerPosition}" required>
     <option value="0">Select position for player</option>
<!--HERE NEED PROPER REQUEST -->
     <option th:selected="${player.playerPosition}"  th:text="${player.playerPosition}"></option>
     <option value="GK">Goalkeeper</option>
     <option value="RWB">Right Wingback</option>
     <option value="RCB">Right Centreback</option> 
     (...)
</select>
```

Comment: ok, tried and found such request with thymeleaf conditional: <option th:if="${player.playerPosition!=null}"
                                            th:selected="${player.playerPosition}" th:text="${player.playerPosition}"></option> it's not excactly how I expected but gives some solution

Comment: If you think your solution will help future visitors to your question, you can write it as an answer, instead of a comment. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) You can also accept your own answer, so others can see it worked for you.  Or you can wait, and see if you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

as per kindly advice:
ok, tried and found such request with thymeleaf conditional:

```
<option th:if="${player.playerPosition!=null}" th:selected="${player.playerPosition}" th:text="${player.playerPosition}"></option>
```

it's not excactly how I expected but gives some solution –